# Can't use make command Bluetooth

Tags: make, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to downgrade from Bluez5 to Bluez4 in case to use HFP , here what I get  used make after ./configurate command

```
~/bluez-4.101 $ make
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h
ln: target 'lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h' is not a directory
Makefile:5649: recipe for target 'lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h' failed
make: *** [lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h] Error 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when your directory name has spaces, so it was

```
~/foo bar number 2/
```

and I changed it to

```
~/foo/
```